# Cartoon from a few years ago, main character is a blacksmith with magic powers

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

A cartoon series about a young blacksmith in training that got magic powers.

He lives with two girls, a monster and an old man and helps defend the land from evil while learning about his powers.

Comment: See also [Cartoon with a boy who has a bracelet with powers, his sister has freezing power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/197455/98028) which has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

That would be [*Lanfeust Quest*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3252702/) (2013), a cartoon adaptation the eponymous French bande dessinée set in the *Lanfeust de Troy* universe.

In this world, almost everyone has an unique power, and the main character's is being able to melt metal. He happens to be a blacksmith apprentice.

Among his friends are Cixi and C'ian, daughters of Nicolède, the village's typical old, "wise" man. And the monster you were referring to would be Hébus, a troll.

Below is a still of the show's main characters.

[image: Lanfeust Quest characters]

Comment: Don't be daft that isn't what Thanos looks like.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot it's his evil twin. Or not. :p