# Cartoon with a boy who has a bracelet with powers, his sister has freezing power

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

When I was younger I saw a cartoon.

There was a boy with a bracelet which had powers, and some of them in the village had powers like freezing or invisibility. The boy's sister had freezing power.

The villain used to live in a big dragon's back.

The bracket had both negative and positive energy the negative energy was purple in colour.

Comment: Hey there! Roughly when were you "younger"? 80s, three years ago? :) Also, the villain living in a dragon's back - did you mean _on_ the dragon's back, or does the dragon have some kind of special room in its back? Any idea which channel/streaming site you watched that on?

Comment: This sounds like Lanfeust of Troy.

Comment: Thanks its lanfeust quest and i am 17 now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be Lanfeust Quest. The work is derived from the universe of Lanfeust of Troy (a French comic), although it's quite far from the original.

In the animation, Lanfeust has a magic bracelet which he uses to wield powers (unlike the comic's magomamoth ivory):

[image: Lanfeust's magic bracelet]

And here is a picture of Thanos' dragon ship (found by @Jenayah):

[image: Thanos' dragon ship]

As in the comic, Cixi can manipulate ici. There's not a lot of evidence for this, but you have this cover of Lanfeust de Troy and [an extract at the start of Black Sun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5oIYgC7aic&feature=youtu.be&t=50).

[image: Cover of Lanfeust de Troy no.6, showing Cixi in a pool of ice]

Answer (score 0):

It's called legend of the dragon and has two seasons

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain why this is the correct answer and how it matches the OP's description? It is worth noting, however, that the work here has [already been identified](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/197456/58193).